# Unable to deploy the image in the kubernetes (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am stuck in the last moment , cannot figure out the mistake , everything is working fine , but while deploying the image on the cluster getting the error:

The image is in the docker hub , from the aws , i used docker login , provided the credential also .

```
sudo kops validate cluster --state=s3://kops-storage-54321 -o yaml
```

output :

```
Using cluster from kubectl context: tests.k8s.local

nodes:
- hostname: ip-172-20-40-124.us-east-2.compute.internal
  name: ip-172-20-40-124.us-east-2.compute.internal
  role: master
  status: "True"
  zone: us-east-2a
- hostname: ip-172-20-112-165.us-east-2.compute.internal
  name: ip-172-20-112-165.us-east-2.compute.internal
  role: node
  status: "True"
  zone: us-east-2c
- hostname: ip-172-20-60-168.us-east-2.compute.internal
  name: ip-172-20-60-168.us-east-2.compute.internal
  role: node
  status: "True"
  zone: us-east-2a
```

Docker Login :

```
sudo docker login

Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/ubuntu/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

while deploying the image getting the error:

Command:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-176:~$  sudo kubectl create deployment magicalnginx --image=amitranjan007/magicalnginx
```

Error:

```
error: no matches for extensions/, Kind=Deployment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which apis support current Kubernetes object using

```
$ kubectl api-resources | grep deployment
deployments                       deploy       apps                           true         Deployment
```

This means that only apiVersion with apps is correct for Deployments (extensions is not supporting Deployment) from kubernetes version 1.16.

**Change apiVersion to apps/v1 in deployment yaml.**

Comment: sudo kubectl api-resources | grep deployment
Error: unknown command "api-resources" for "kubectl"

Comment: what is the output of kubectl version

Comment: Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.0", GitCommit:"925c127ec6b946659ad0fd596fa959be43f0cc05", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-15T21:07:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.7", GitCommit:"be3d344ed06bff7a4fc60656200a93c74f31f9a4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-11T19:24:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: kubectl client is too old..please upgrade

Comment: updated : Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}